# Share internet (with same IP address)

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, bluetooth

I am currently housing in a place that allows only a limited number of devices connected to the internet. Problem: I have more devices than allowed. So I have one Ubuntu machine which is connected via Ethernet and now **I would like to share it's connection, but without that the connected device generates an new IP** (via DHCP) and thus wouldnt count up against the limit. Available interfaces: WiFi and Bluetooth. I want the devices connected to my Ububtu machine to go out to the internet AS the Ubuntu machine.

What technologies / protocols /  permit this? Forgive me if it is a stupid question, but I dont understand well all the different networking technologies. Thanks a lot already for any hint!!

Answer (score 2):

Your simplest option is to use a switch/router with NAT capability to present one IP address to the outside world, while allowing you to use as many machines as you like.

Such devices are very low cost.

[Useful entry level Wikipedia article on NAT here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I will have this as plan B then. Best case would be I can use the router and/or Ubuntu machine I already have in the household. So I should look for NAT options in my router?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings -> network. Select wireless. And press the button "use as hotspot". Write down the connection key and let your devices connect.

More info about sharing your connection:

[Internet/connectionSharing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)

Comment: Thanks, but in my experience, this has led to problems because either some Android devices could not connect or (this one I am not sure) the connected devices get assigned a new IP.